# copying over data from a union in C

Tags: c, pointers

I've got a pointer to a struct with a union

so let's say we have

```
struct A {
  union {
    char **word;
    struct A *B
  } u;
};
```

and I have variables x and y of type A*

```
typedef A* A_t;
A_t x;
A_t y;
```

would x->u = y->u be enough to copy over stuff in the union.

Comment: That statement will cause segfault for sure!

Comment: BTW: `typedef A* A_t;` is a syntax error in C. Are you using a C++ compiler? BTW2: typedeffing pointers should be considered a bad habit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just dereference pointers if they are not pointing to anything valid.
To be able to do `x->u` you have to make sure `x` points to some valid memory, The code you show dereferences an uninitialized pointer which causes an Undefined Behavior and most likely a crash. Same applies for `y->u`. So make sure `x` and `y` point to valid memory before you dereference them.

```
x->u = y->u
```

Will not perform a **deep copy** but a **shallow copy**.
You will basically end up with two pointers pointing to the same memory, which is not probably what you intend or need.

If you need a deep copy, you should allocate your destination enough memory to hold the data being copied to it and then use `memcpy` to copy the contents of the source union to it.

**Good Read:**
[What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: He'd better allocate some space for x and y to point to, first.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Hmm, Ofcourse,  I assumed OP would do so.Anyways since you brought it up I will add a note about it.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Assuming all pointers are initialized correctly, x->u = y->u really is "enough to copy over stuff in the union", the "stuff in the union" being either a pointer-to-pointer-to-char or pointer-to-struct-A. This has the same effect as memcpy(&x->u, &y->u, sizeof(x->u)); Of course, whatever the relevant pointer points to will not be touched or copied and that's not what was asked.